Make tkinter bind use keycode rather than keysym for language agnostic bindings
I'm working on Tkinter Python programs where I need to switch between Greek and other languages for input. My problem is that I then have to rewrite every key binding using  and check for keycode to execute the correct function.
widget.bind(<Control-z>, undo)
It will not work with a keyboard layout like Greek. However, if one could specify the keycode rather than the keysym, it would be easier.
widget.bind(<Control-Keycode-52>, undo)
I have already made my own Entry widget to deal with this, but it involved having to write new copy, paste, select, move to end, etc..., functions. Then I have to do the same for Toplevel windows etc... which is a lot of work.
Is there such a solution already in some libraries or does somebody have an elegant way to handle this?

I think there is no direct way to bind to the Keycode. You'll have to use a workaround to do what you want.
One way is to make a general binding to <KeyPress> and add some if-else statements to check for a specific Keycode.
But I thought about generalizing the code so that instead of just using checks, it is be possible to generate special events that widgets could be bind to. Code example:
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


def generate_keycode_event(event: tk.Event):
    pressed_widget: tk.Widget = event.widget
    special = ''

    if isinstance(event.state, int):  # probably not needed
        state = event.state

        mods = {'Shift': 0, 'Control': 2, 'Alt': 17}
        for key in mods:
            if state & (1 << mods[key]):
                special += key + '-'

    pressed_widget.event_generate(f"<<{special}Keycode-{event.keycode}>>", x=event.x, y=event.y, sendevent=event.send_event)


root.bind('<KeyPress>', generate_keycode_event)

ent = tk.Entry()
ent.pack()
ent.bind('<<Control-Keycode-90>>', lambda e: print('Undo!'))  # Keycode-90 is "z"


root.mainloop()

This code should allow you to do what you want without using if tests. But this is probably not an ideal code. There may be some problems.
Some notes on the code:

Since I am using a root binding, if you need to bind some other keys to the root, you will have to add the add='+' parameter at the end of the extra bindings.

If desired, you can add several additional mods. For example, if you want to define the "Lock" key used, you can add "Lock": 1 to "mods". Just experiment with event.state for additional mods. There are some that I found:
extra_mods = {'Shift': 0, 'Lock': 1, 'Control': 2, 'Mod1': 3, 'Mod2': 4, 'Mod3': 5, 
              'Mod4': 6, 'Mod5': 7, 'Button1': 8, 'Button2': 9, 'Button3': 10, 
              'Button4': 11, 'Button5': 12, 'Alt': 17, 'NumLock': 18}


On Windows, the key code for "z" is 90, but it may be different on another operating system.



Thank you! I'll test out your code. I' always using add="+" anyways. Surprised that keycode is different on windows and linux. Then I would need to figure out how to get the correct keycode per os. However, I only use Linux so I guess I'll leave that issue for another day.
